close browser tab after successful download file
I'm working on WOPI app. I created WOPI host page and execute this endpoint:
/wv/WordViewer/request.pdf?WOPISrc={WopiUrl}&type=downloadpdf

that download file (convert .docx to .pdf and download).
After successful downloading I want to close browser tab.
I just hardcoded this way:
var o = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
var iframeDoc = o.contentWindow.document;

checkIframeLoaded();

function checkIframeLoaded() {
    console.log(iframeDoc.readyState);
    if (iframeDoc.readyState == 'complete') {
        window.close();
    } else {
        setTimeout(checkIframeLoaded, 1000);
    }
}

But it isn't what I want, it closes the tab after DOMContentLoaded success but .pdf document wasn't downloaded
Maybe there is a way to catch all requests are completed or something else? I just need to check somehow that /wv/WordViewer/request.pdf?WOPISrc={WopiUrl}&type=downloadpdf successfully completed.

Was this tab not opened by a script (window.open())? Then you may have this problem.

@NilsLindemann script works but I want to close browser window after document was successfully downloaded and not when page was loaded.

I did not ask if the script works. You can only close a tab using JavaScript, when you created that tab using that same JavaScript. This is for security reasons. Read more in the currently most upvoted answer to the linked question.

In other words, try opening that URL in a new tab using window.open(), save the returned window handle, get feedback from it when the downloading is done (e.g. using Broadcast channel), then close the opened tab using window_handle.close().

Why are you opening a tab in the first place? Just point the user directly to the download URL.

since readyState indicates that the load event is about to fire. please try to add an actual load event handler to the iframe like iframe.onload = function() { window.close() }; before changing its src. It's just an attempt.. I'm suggesting that strategy because it seems you are using an iframe to load the pdf url, but I'm not sure. The whole picture is not pretty clear from what you shared so far
